# gamSpline Caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, spline, gam

How do I choose the optimal df(degrees of freedom) for my splines?
I used poisson regression and splines that help me to adjust for non linear changes. Using the caret package, I used the `train` function with `method = gamSpline` to test only 3 df.

```
model <- train(
  RBC ~ elapsed, 
  obgyn_aleph,
  method = "gamSpline",
  trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv", 
    number = 10,
    verboseIter = TRUE
  )
)
```

Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting df = 3 on full training set

Is this the default? If so how I can change it?

Tnx,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The tuneGrid argument allows the user to specify a custom grid of tuning parameters, in this case, `df`

```
 model <- train(
      RBC ~ elapsed, 
      obgyn_aleph,
      method = "gamSpline",
      trControl = trainControl(
        method = "cv", 
        number = 10,
        verboseIter = TRUE
      ),
      tuneGrid = data.frame(df=seq(2,20,by=2))
    )
```